# Search class by author in IntellijIdea

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea

I have a big (1000+ classes) project with many (20+) programmers. Is there any possibility in `IntellijIdea` to see all classes created by a concrete author?

**PS:** I mean inner `IntellijIdea` functions, not the regular expression for a custom parser.

Comment: when u use git, you can try to click on the line numbers (left of the code) and the click "Annotate", perhaps you can find a filter to get all the code of one programmer... but i don't know

Comment: does your project contain @author annotations? in the javadoc of the given classes?

Comment: @user503413 yes, it does

Comment: @SleepyX667 hmm..click "Annotate" for an every of 1000+ classes? Unusual step :)

Comment: When you have JavaDoc with name... why you don't make a search for that name on the whole project?  --> "Find in Path" --> @author name

Comment: I've tried it with `Double Shift`, it doesn't work

Comment: don't use double shift. Right click on project structure (left window  -> project) and then `Find in Path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be, to right-click in the project window, on a package (or the whole project) and then on `Find in Path`. Here you can write in the string to search `@author name`. To search all java classes with JavaDoc with the author 'name'.

Comment: It's a workaround. It wold be better to use the git (or whatever) informations (like the annotations (git blame))